# How to create a sequence number based on my result set?

Tags: oracle

This is how my table currently looks

```
    Month   Product     Value
---------------------------------
    1       Shoes       12.00
    1       Jacket      15.00
    2       Shirt       3.00
```

I need to add a column that generates a MonthlySaleID that increments for each month and resets each time the month changes, like so

```
    Month   Product     Value   MonthlySaleID
------------------------------------------------
    1       Shoes       12.00   1
    1       Jacket      15.00   2
    2       Shirt       3.00    1
```

Any clues would be great

Comment: We can provide you with an easy answer for this. But I'd like to know more of the general problem since I have a feeling we rethink the solution.

Comment: i'm not sure what more I could add to the question. Do you need clarification? I've been asked to generate a report that behaves like I have described with an in incrementing id per month

Comment: So, you don't need a new column, here you go. What about a view? Especially for reports, they usually ask for some sort of visualisation customizations that don't really belong to NF1-6. It's better to create dedicated views for them and leave the standard model untouched, if possible.

Comment: It is already a view

Comment: Could you provide with the current view definition? So I can adjust my answeR?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this view then:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vw_rpt_sales AS
SELECT month, product, value, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY month ORDER BY Product) AS MonthlySaleID
FROM 
    originaltable;
```

Couldn't test the rank function, in theory it should return what you want. I ordered by Product because it didn't seem in your question that you had a sale ID information. But if you have it, it's better to order by SaleID I suppose.

Comment: I think you should try `ROW_NUMBER` instead `RANK`

Comment: `this doesn't work`. Could you be more precise? Also. I asked you for more information as, as it stands, it looks like you don't want anyone to help you.